# How to divide the time series into intervals(not equal interval) and sum value in each interval using python

Tags: python, simulation

Greeting All,

I have two large tables I get it from the network simulation. 
The first table looks like this:

```
name      time    previousTime   nextTime
A         4.22       0.00          4.23
B         4.32       4.22          9.22
A         9.22       4.32          9.23
C         9.32       9.22          10.1
A         10.1       9.23          10.1
```

and the second table looks like:

```
name      time      value 
A         4.11       2
B         4.32       1
A         4.22       0
C         9.32       4
A         4.5        1
A         9.5        8
A         9.6        4
```

what I want to do, take the row from the first table and check in the second table all the rows where time in the second table between previousTime   nextTime or equal previousTime or nextTime or both of them. then sum the value as a new column in the first table.

I expected the output as follows:

```
name      time    previousTime   nextTime    Value 
A         4.22       0.00          4.23        2
B         4.32       4.22          9.22        1
A         9.22       4.23          9.23        1
C         9.32       9.22          10.1        4
A         10.1       9.23          10.1        12
```

I wrote this python code but given me different values

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import csv

con = sqlite3.connect("G1.db")
cur = con.cursor()

result =[]
value =[]

q1= cur.execute("SELECT Name,Time,PreviousValue,NextValue from table1 GROUP by SourceName,Time")

rq1 = q1.fetchall()


q2=cur.execute("SELECT Time from table2")

rq2 = q2.fetchall()
print(rq2)


for row in rq1:
      result.append(row)  
print(result[0])
len(rq1)

#start my code
for i in range(len(rq1)):
    for j in range(len(rq2)):
        name = result[i][j]
        T = result[i][j+1]
        P = result[i][j+2]
        N = result[i][j+3]

        print('Name =',name)
        print('P =',P)
        print('T =',T)
        print('N =',N)
        q3= cur.execute("SELECT time,value,sum(value) AS Tsum\
                 from table2\
                 where (Name LIKE '%' || ? || '%' AND (time > ? AND time <= ?)) OR (Name LIKE '%' || ? || '%' AND time == ? ) ",(name,P,N,name,P))

        rq3 = q3.fetchall()
        print (rq3)
        q3len = len(rq3)
        v1 = rq3[j][j+1]
        print('q3 ',rq3[j][j+1])
        value.append(v1)
print (value)
len(value)
```

Any help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for you

```
import pandas as pd

c1 = pd.Series(["A", "B", "A", "C","A"])
c2 = pd.Series([4.22,4.32,9.22,9.32,10.1])
c3 = pd.Series([0.00,4.22,4.32,9.22,9.32])
c4 = pd.Series([4.23,9.22,9.23,10.1,10.1])
c5 = pd.Series([])

Data ={'name':c1, 'time':c2, 'previousTime':c3, 'nextTime': c4, "sum_": c5} # Define Data
table1 = pd.DataFrame(Data)              # Create DataFrame


c1 = pd.Series(["A","B","A","C","A","A","A"])
c2 = pd.Series([4.11,4.32,4.22,9.32,4.5,9.5,9.6])
c3 = pd.Series([2,1,0,4,1,8,4])

Data ={'name':c1, 'time':c2, 'value':c3} # Define Data
table2 = pd.DataFrame(Data)              # Create DataFrame



for idx, row in table1.iterrows():
    counter = 0
    for _, elm_row in table2.iterrows():
        if row.previousTime <= elm_row.time <= row.nextTime:
            counter += 1
    table1.sum_[idx] = int(counter)
```

===================================================================
You may need to do some tweaks but this will work

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

con = pyodbc.connect("G1.db")

sql = "SELECT Name,Time,PreviousValue,NextValue from table1 GROUP by SourceName,Time"
table1 = pd.read_sql(sql, con)


sql_ = "SELECT Time from table2"

table2 = pd.read_sql(sql_, con)



result = []

for idx, row in table1.iterrows():
    counter = 0
    for _, elm_row in table2.iterrows():
        if row.previousTime <= elm_row.time <= row.nextTime:
            counter += 1
    result.append(counter)

temp_fr = pd.DataFrame({"sum_": result})

table1.join(temp_fr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but your code gives me the wrong result. for example the total sum value in table 2 is 240 and after running the code I expecting when summing the result array for A in table1 240, but I get 280 !!!

Comment: check by removing the equal to conditions

Comment: Its fairly simple code as you can see. It may be possible that content of your 2nd table may be wrong. or you might need to remove the duplicate entries.